# How can you change this message which is in block cipher AES-256 in CBC?

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, initialization-vector, padding-oracle

Given is the secret message encrypted with AES-256 in CBC mode

```
5a04ec902686fb05a6b7a338b6e07760 14c4e6965fc2ed2cd358754494aceffa
```

The first 16 Byte is the initial vector, the second 16 Byte is the
ciphertext. The plaintext of the secret message above is (ASCII-encoded) `We're blown. Run`

How can you change the secret message such that you get `Meeting tonight!` if you decrypt it?

---

I'm not sure how to do this correctly but I found some graphic that describes the way CBC is decrypted:

[image]

Because the plaintext is ASCII encoded, we should have in total one planetext block because the message `We're blown. Run` is made up of exactly 16 characters. But all in all, I don't really understand how I can change the secret message to get the message `Meeting tonight!` ? : /

Comment: Hint: What happens to the decryption result if you XOR some arbitrary value $\Delta$ (16-bytes) into the IV?

Comment: @SEJPM If you XOR some arbitrary value with the initial value, it then gets encrypted and takes one block size. For further iterations, the output of this encrypted block is used instead of the initial vector. At least that's how I got it from the graphic :s

Comment: @roblind The plaintext is exactly 16 bytes long. Therefore the block cipher algorithm is performed exactly exactly once if no padding is used. Therefore there are no further iterations. Note that you are actually changing the IV without changing ciphertext. After the sender encrypts. Before the recipient decrypts. How does the *decrypted* value change when you change specific bits in the IV.

Comment: (new^old)^old = new by properties of xor (^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram you have there is for encryption... decryption is basically upside down:

[image: CBC Mode Decryption]

Notice that the ciphertext is decrypted and *then* XORed to produce the plaintext. You simply need to manipulate the IV to change the output of the first block

Comment: Which is why you should not forget to take the IV into account when performing encrypt- then-MAC, and why authenticated ciphers  always include the IV as well.